# Can we have multiple rules with same target?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Can we have multiple rules with same target? Here pre-requisites will change. I am using 3.82 make version. Where it will pick the length of the steam (% symbol match ) to determine which rule to pick among multiple conflicting pattern rules. Wtih 3.81 version it works fine as expected. But with 3.82 it is picking wrong rule.

Eg: -  We have two rules below

```
$(TGTDIR)/$(TGT_EXAMPLES_UVM)/%: $(SRC_EXAMPLES_UVM)/%
$(copy_test)

$(TGTDIR)/$(TGT_EXAMPLES_UVM)/bug_fix/%: $(SRC_EXAMPLES_UVM)/common_src/%
$(copy_test)
```

SRC_EXAMPLES_UVM value is 'example/uvm'. Inside /uvm folder we have bug_fix/ folder with some files in it. Some files are common (i.e same name) in  common_src/ & bug_fix/ folders. For those files make has to run first rule above. But in newer version 3.82 it is running second rule, to fix it i want to have a separate rule below for /bug_fix/ folder . Is this the right way to fix it? Because target will become same in this case ? I am new to make. Can Anyone  please help?

```
$(TGTDIR)/$(TGT_EXAMPLES_UVM)/bug_fix/%: $(SRC_EXAMPLES_UVM)/bug_fix/%
$(copy_test)
```

Comment: If stems are of the same length, then the more recent  rule wins. So, if I understand you correctly, the last "addition" should solve your problem. So what's the problem then? "Can we have multiple rules with the same target in make?" Yes, we can. If it's multiple **explicit** rules then the warning will be printed (so it's considered as "a bad practice"); if multiple **implicit** rules then it's perfectly okay for make.

Comment: You're giving version numbers and referencing idiosyncratic features of *GNU* `make`.  It is important to understand that GNU's is only one of several implementations of `make`, though a good and popular one.